# prevent Servlet application from remote access/capturing in mobile browser in java

Tags: java, servlets

we want to prevent remote access/screen recording (third party apps like Anydesk, Quicksuppport, Teamviewer etc.)of my servlet web application/Mobile browser in java. we are using hybrid app we already disabled the remote access for app but unable to disable from the mobile browser.

```
Android app: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)) but how we can prevent in the mobile browser
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent my application from remote access/capturing in mobile browser in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638027/prevent-my-application-from-remote-access-capturing-in-mobile-browser-in-java)

Comment: it  is not have any solution mentioned in that question

Comment: That is an auto comment. What I flagged was that you have asked the same question twice. It is better to edit your first question and add enough details so we can help you with it.

Comment: How to detect a remote access app is running on Android mobile browser

Comment: How to  get currently running application package name in Cordova